# Infinite summation with absolute value

Tags: summation

Recently I need to compute the summation like the following form:

```
Sum[t^Abs[n - m], {n, -∞, ∞}, Assumptions -> m ∈ Integers]
```

But *Mathematica* cannot figure it out:

[image]

Although it would be simple to compute without `m`:

[image]

I wonder why and how could I solve it?

Comment: Note that the second result is not correct without additional assumptions.

Answer (score 5):

This sum is indeed possible to compute as it is using the `FourierSequenceTransform`. Some algorithms of MA are obviously more advanced than others:

```
s = FourierSequenceTransform[t^Abs[n - m], n, w, Assumptions -> m \[Element] Integers]
(*(E^(-I (-1 + m) w) (-1 + t^2))/((E^(I w) - t) (-1 + E^(I w) t))*)
```

Now we recall that for $w\rightarrow 0$ the desired sum is obtained

```
Cancel[s/. w -> 0]
(*(1 + t)/(1 - t)*)
```

And, as @Michael E2 noticed, one should pay attention to the radius of convergence of the sum.

Comment: Thank you! But how about a even complex summation, like this one: `Sum[t^(1/2 (Abs[n - m1] + Abs[n - m2]) + 3/2 (Abs[m1] + Abs[m2]) + 
    m2 - m1), {n, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, {m2, -\[Infinity], \
\[Infinity]}, {m1, m2, \[Infinity]}]` This summation should have a simple result, as I have computed it manually. But mathematica can't solve this summation using above method

Comment: @user27490 How have you reformulated your sum `m1`to run in infinite limits? Only then it will be suitable for Fourier methods.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to help to explicitly expand `Abs`, which by default is a function over the complexes, for a real/integer argument:

```
Assuming[
 {k, m} ∈ Integers,
 Sum[t^Abs[k - m] // PiecewiseExpand, {k, -∞, ∞}, 
  Assumptions -> m ∈ Integers && Abs[t] < 1]
 ]
(*  (-1 - t)/(-1 + t)  *)
```

---

Follow-up to comment:

Maybe deconstruct the pieces semi-manually?  (I assume `Sum` does something like this above, but gives up here.)

```
summand = Assuming[{k, m1, m2} ∈ Integers, 
   t^(1/2 (Abs[k - m1] + Abs[k - m2]) + 3/2 (Abs[m1] + Abs[m2]) + m2 - m1) //
     PiecewiseExpand[#, Method -> {"ConditionSimplifier" -> Simplify}] &
   ];
Simplify@ Total@ Assuming[{k, m1, m2} ∈ Integers,
   Sum[Piecewise[{#}, 0],
      {k, -∞, ∞}, {m2, -∞, ∞}, {m1, m2, ∞}, 
      Assumptions -> k ∈ Integers && m1 ∈ Integers && m2 ∈ Integers && Abs[t] < 1] & /@ 
    Append[First@summand, {Last@summand, Or @@ summand[[1, All, 2]] // Not // Reduce}]
   ]
(*  -((1 + 4 t + 4 t^2 + 5 t^3 + 4 t^4) / ((-1 + t)^3 (1 + t + t^2)))  *)
```

Comment: Thank you! But how about a even complex summation, like this one:   `Assuming[{n, m1, m2} \[Element] Integers, 
 Sum[t^(1/2 (Abs[n - m1] + Abs[n - m2]) + 3/2 (Abs[m1] + Abs[m2]) + 
      m2 - m1) // 
   PiecewiseExpand, {n, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, {m2, \
-\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, {m1, m2, \[Infinity]}, 
  Assumptions -> 
   n \[Element] Integers && m1 \[Element] Integers && 
    m2 \[Element] Integers && Abs[t] < 1]]`   This summation should have a simple result, as I have computed it manually. But mathematica can't solve this summation using above method.

Comment: @user27490 : Instead of adding essentially the same comment to every answer, could you instead update your question so that it is *actually* the question you want answered?